# What happens when we try to access array elements?

Tags: arrays, associative-array

You might guess what I mean by looking at the heading.
I was looking at some algorithms that operate on aggregate data types like arrays. I can very confidently say that I know what arrays are and why we use them. But I have no idea how they internally work. For instance, what happens when I do this:

```
anArray [10];
```

What is happening behind the scenes?  Is my computer directly reaches to 10th index (seems extremely efficient) or it reaches to index 10 by starting from 0, and stepping forward untill it finds [10]. If it does it directly, then what about associative arrays? Keys in an associative array can be a string, right? Does the computer tries to match the keys left to right, or reaches directly to the index/key we enclosed in square brackets.

Comment: It mostly depends on the language you're using, but in most cases it will go directly to the 10th memory cell of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal, usual array (FORTRAN, C, Java arrays) you access the indexed location directly without any iterations over other elements. For the single-dimensional array, the array index is multiplied by the array member size, giving direct memory offset (counting from the start of array). FORTRAN had `equivalence` operator to place 1D array over 2D array (same memory location) so it was obvious how these are laid down. C also allows to access array through pointers, and there it is clear that the memory offset is simply index multiplied by the size of the element.

Some languages do introduce 'arrays' that are much more like the other data structure (a map). They are most often implemented through the hash table and have the constant access time - slower than direct access but not much dependent on the number of elements in the array.